# TypeError: map is undefined When using google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am running into this issue while trying to implement a google map for the site that I am maintaining. I am getting the following error from firebug:

> TypeError: map is undefined

What did I do wrong?

*Note*: We just change the domain last week.

Thank you

```
<div id="mapd" style="width: 100%; height: 550px;"></div>
<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var markers = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infoWindow;


function load1() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapd"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.00, 72.22),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(ev){   
    var s = $("#searchcheck").is(':checked');
    if(s==true)
    {
      $('#loading').css('display','block');
      $('#loading1').css('display','block');
      searchLocationsNear(map.getCenter());
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: if you have changed domain then it has to updated to [app](https://console.developers.google.com/) where key is associated.

Comment: @Deep3015 I just added the key today since the older domain was before 2016 so the key is pointing to the right domain.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  I don't get the reported error with the posted code (the `load1` function is never called, so no map). Note that the posted code has a syntax error (missing the opening `<`), but that produces a different error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`).

Comment: When do you call `load1`?  Which line in your code throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you haven't added your google map api key in the library. you can find with key word 'myKey' in library.

1. Get google api key [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)
2. replace "myKey" with the key google provided.
3. Try again.

**Try This Code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <div id="mapd" style="    width: 100%;
        height: 550px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 11;float: inherit;
        display: block;"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var markers1 = [];
    var infoWindow;


    function initMap() {

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapd"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.00, 72.22),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(ev){   
        var s = $("#searchcheck").is(':checked');
        if(s==true)
        {
          $('#loading').css('display','block');
          $('#loading1').css('display','block');
          searchLocationsNear(map.getCenter());
        }
      });

    }

    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA1TwYksj1uQg1V_5yPUZqwqYYtUIvidrY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: **myKey** is written because OP does not want to disclose the real key

Comment: Try my solution you will get want you want.

Comment: see in the last comment above your answer ,OP has already generated key today